# How to check if a post is in categories x,y,z inludint their subcategories

Tags: single, categories

I am trying to check whether a post is in categories X, Y, Z (including the subcategories within them).

This is the piece of code I have tried in my single.php:

```
if ( in_category(array( '1', '2', '3', ) ) {
                    echo "This post is in the selected categories or their subcategories";
                              }
                else {
                echo "this post inst in the categories or the subs.";
                          }
```

I have also tried using the post_is_in_descendant_category (included the function from the codex above my code) but it still wont display true. Including the function
This is my code I used on test 2#:

```
    if ( in_category(array( '1', '2', '3', ) ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( array( '1', '2', '3', ) ) ) {
                    echo "This post is in the selected categories or their subcategories";
                              }
                else {
                echo "this post inst in the categories or the subs.";
                          }
```

Answer (score 1):

`post_is_in_descendant_category` is not a WP function. If you don't define it, it doesn't exist. I think that you have read the docs for `in_category()` function and have taken [`post_is_in_descendant_category` from the example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category) without read it completely. Add this code to functions.php or in a plugin:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now `post_is_in_descendant_category()` is defined and you can use it. Remember to use `in_category()` or `post_is_in_descendant_category()` inside The loop, if not, you need to pass the post ID or object to check.

NOTE: You are using `array( '1', '2', '3', )`. The values inside the array are strings; I think you refer to categories with ID 1, 2 and 3. To pass cateogories IDs you have pass the values as integer: `array( 1, 2, 3 )`. Also note that `post_is_in_descendant_category` only accepts category IDs as integer values.

Comment: Thank you forgot to mention I had added that function already but still it shows as if the post isn't in the category or any of the subcategories of the 1, 2, 3 . Do you see any error in my code? I cant seem to find whats wrong with it.

Comment: Are the code used inside The loop?

Comment: Im beginner with wordpress, but I think so. Above that code is:
if ( have_posts() ){
    while (have_posts()){
     the_post(); ...etc

Comment: Your code must be inside the `while` loop after `the_post();` and before closing the `while` loop. If not, you must pass a post ID or post object to the `in_category()` and `post_is_in_descendant_category()` functions.

Comment: I have found out why it wasnt working the first field "in_category(array( 'fruits', 'vegetables', 'shoes', )" needs to be with the categories names and not IDs now it works fine! I have updated the answer with additional info and explanation.

Comment: You are wrong, `in_category` accepts ID (integer) or slugs (string). Maybe your problem is that you are using category ID as string: `array('1', '2', '3')` has string values inside.; `array(1, 2, 3)` has integer values. If my answer solve your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.